# Reprojecting layer from Gauss-Krueger to epsg:25832 (with example file to try)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a file which, when opened in QGIS, is shifted and has a lot of tarball-conversions suggested. However, none of them works correctly, meaning, when I load the data into qgis, then adding a basemap (xyz-layer), the data is shifted.

As it even seems to fail to load correctly in QGIS, I tried it in Arcmap, as it seems to have an ESRI-CRS.
What I did so far (in ArcMap, as in QGIS already the loading is problematic):

- change the projection to epsg: 31467, as it seems to be a Gauß-Krüger-Projection.
- then transform to epsg:25832

However, when I do this, the layer still does not correctly align in a basemap with epsg:25832.

It would be really helpful if someone would try it with the example file, which can be downloaded here:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/jr8g5v92h7azi73xf9cjw/h?rlkey=xgb5pk3z4rrqvl7um1v8scp9h&dl=0

I absolutely prefer QGIS or PyQGIS to work with, so if one finds a solution in QGIS would be awesome. That I use here ArcMap is just because the data is already shifted when loaded into QGIS.

This is how the file needs to be laying: The street marked with the arrow should be the boundary.
[image]

The original CRS as shown in ArcMap is this:

```
PROJCS[
       "Germany_Zone_3",
       GEOGCS[
              "GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",
               DATUM[
                    "D_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",
                     SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]
                     ],
               PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
               UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]
              ],
       PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
       PARAMETER["False_Easting",3500000.0],
       PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
       PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],
       PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],
       PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
       UNIT["Meter",1.0]
      ]
```

Comment: Does it show in the desired place in ArcMap or not?

Comment: When you load the example file in ArcMap without doing anything with it, it shows in the correct spot, as shown in the image. However, when I reproject it, it shifts south-west, crossing the marked street.

Comment: Without touching/changing anything, no reprojection etc: What info can you get out of ArcMap for the CRS of the loaded layer?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I have now included the CRS in the question-text above. Does this help?

Comment: I think that implies that the GCS is wrong. Maybe it's already on ETRS89, but using the parameter values of the Germany zone 3.